# Regex for matching string with trailing whitespace works in Perl but not Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find strings that have trailing whitespace, i.e. 'foo ' as opposed to 'foo'.

In Perl, I would use:

```
$str = 'foo ';
print "Match\n" if ($str =~ /\s+$/) ;
```

When I try this in Python 2.6, e.g.:

```
import re

str = 'foo '
if re.match('\s+$', str):
    print 'Match'
```

it doesn't match.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the quick responses.  I knew it had to be something pretty simple.

Comment: You should also notice that the answers use a *raw string* for the regex as well, i.e. `r'\s+$'` where 'r' is before the quotes.  This prevents python from treating escaped characters as special.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`re.search()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) instead; `re.match()` only matches at the *start* of a string. Quoting the [`re.match()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match):

> If zero or more characters **at the beginning of *string*** match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding `MatchObject` instance.

Emphasis mine.

In other words, `re.match()` is the equivalent of the `m/.../` match operator in Perl, while `re.search()` is the same as `/.../`.

Answer (score 2):

Because `re.match(r'\s+$', str)` is equivalent to `re.search(r'\A\s+$', str)`. Use `re.search` instead.

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match):

> `re.match()` checks for a match only at the beginning of the string,
>   while `re.search()` checks for a match anywhere in the string (this is
>   what **Perl** does by default).

Comment: Not quite; it is equivalent to `re.search('\A\s+$', str)`, a subtle difference.