# Am I misunderstanding Python regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

So, I am finding that

```
re.match("[^0-9.]","50-100")
```

Does not match anything.  Can anyone tell me why?

I am convinced that the `-` should indicate a character range and the `^` should negate the set.

Python 2.7.2.

Comment: Dup: [Regex for matching string with trailing whitespace works in Perl but not Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120422/regex-for-matching-string-with-trailing-whitespace-works-in-perl-but-not-python)

Comment: What condition do you want to check for `"50-100"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`re.match()` matches from the start of the string *only*, as if the pattern was prepended with the `\A` anchor. Use [`re.search()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) instead:

```
>>> re.search("[^0-9.]","50-100")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10e2a5e00>
>>> re.search("[^0-9.]","50-100").group()
'-'
```

Answer (score 4):

[`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) matches only at the beginning of the input string (unlike [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search))

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match("[^0-9.]","50-100")
>>> re.search("[^0-9.]","50-100")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000002A28100>
>>> re.search("^[^0-9.]","50-100") # re.match("[^0-9.]","50-100") equivalent.
>>>
```

See [search() vs. match()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match).